# Apache Commons: UnsupportedZipFeatureException (LZMA)

Tags: java, zip, unzip, apache-commons, apache-commons-compress

I want to unzip .zip files (with .jpg files inside) that were created using Windows 10's zipping feature.

First I tested it with Java 8's native `util.zip.ZipEntry` but kept getting an `invalid CEN header (bad compression method)` error, which seems to be caused by an incompatibility with Win10's compression.

Because of that I switched to Apache Common's `Compress` library (version 1.2). The first two images in the archive unzip fine but the third always throws an exception:

> org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.UnsupportedZipFeatureException:
> Unsupported compression method 14 (LZMA) used in entry image3.jpg

How do I fully unzip this archive with the `Compress` library? Is that even possible?

My code:

```
ZipFile z = new ZipFile(zippath);
Enumeration<ZipArchiveEntry> entries = z.getEntries();

while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Entry: "+entry.getName());
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(unzipfolder+"\\"+entry.getName()));
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(z.getInputStream(entry));
    byte[] buffer=new byte[1000000];
    int len=0;

    while((len=bis.read(buffer,0,1000000))>0) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, len)  ;
    }
    bis.close();
    bos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tested it with the "LZMA" code provided on the [examples site](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html) (which also includes adding the "xz" [library](https://tukaani.org/xz/java.html)) and even a `CompressorInputStream` but no matter what I did, I kept getting some type of exception, e.g.:

> org.tukaani.xz.UnsupportedOptionsException: Uncompressed size is too
> big

Fortunately there's an inofficial fix for that, posted as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60086933/2016165) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45213793/2016165). The explanation:

> The reason your code isn't working, is that Zip LZMA compressed data
> segments have a different header compared to normal compressed LZMA
> files.

Using `getInputstreamForEntry` (which was posted in the answer), my code is now able to deal with both LZMA and non-LZMA files in a zip archive:

```
ZipFile z = new ZipFile(zipfile);
Enumeration<ZipArchiveEntry> entries = z.getEntries();

while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Entry: "+entry.getName());
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(unzipfolder+"\\"+entry.getName()));
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;

    try {
        bis  = new BufferedInputStream(z.getInputStream(entry));
    } catch(UnsupportedZipFeatureException e) {
        bis  = new BufferedInputStream(getInputstreamForEntry(z, entry));
    }

    byte[] buffer=new byte[1000000];
    int len=0;
                        
    while((len=bis.read(buffer,0,1000000))>0) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, len)  ;
    }
    bis.close();
    bos.close();
}
```